# How to debug two or more files in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging

My debugger works just in one file now (test.js) When I try to debug in another file still debug the test.js   Anybody know the solution for this problem please?

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "type": "node",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Program",
          "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\test.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Debugger for chrome extension in  visual studio .

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I tried what you wrote with chrome extension.. but w. I tried to change the port many times but still not working